# What is the best way to move an object on the screen?

Tags: assembly, graphics, keyboard, x86-16, dosbox

I wanted to know what is the best way for moving an object on the screen - for example: if some kind of shape presented on the screen (on graphic mode), I would like to move it left and right using the keyboard's arrows keys. I know how to read the keyboard buffer. The important thing is that I would like to know is how to move something **smooth** on the screen.

I'm using DOS-Box, with 8086 architecture. And the movement must be on **graphic mode** (320x200).

Comment: You need sprites, and irregular shape represented by a rectangular shape with colored and transparent pixels to define the visible and invisible parts. Assembler is the right language to make sprites fast.

Comment: also see back/double  buffering techniques sometimes they are faster then simple redraw when you got too many objects ... and also it avoids flickering ... to swap buffers you can use single `rep movsb/w/d` ...

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214 and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29296619/2521214 for some ideas ...

Comment: actually there will be only few objects on the screen. I didn't get what you were trying to explain me about the back\double buffering.. can you add a simple code that swaps buffers in the way you suggested?

Comment: @Orange (add `@Spektre` to comment so i get notified ...) with moving objects you need to draw/clear background behind old position of object and then draw object on new position ... when you have too many objects this get slow and flickers so instead you have temporary  screen buffer, draw everything at once there (no background clearing per object needed)  and when done copy the whole to `A000:0000` ...

Comment: @Spektre Ok, I got the logic behind this idea. Now for the technical part- How can I create the temporary buffer? It's suppose to be with 64,000 bytes, but where do I define it? And it won't take most of my memory?

Comment: @Orange you need to allocate extra memory by DOS interrupt I think it was `int 21h` call but not sure it was ages ago ... you got 640 KB at disposal - drivers/services/TSR ... if needed more use XMS or himem but you need add them to config.sys so they actualy load at startup

Comment: @Spektre That's too complicated for my Final project :) . I will try to write straight to VGA and watch how it goes..

Comment: @Orange what assembler compiler you are using? my favorites was TASM later NASM ... if you are interested I could post some simple old 2D game code so you see how to put all together ... (but have no clue what gfx techniques I used back in the days)

Comment: @Spektre I actually have to use TASM..Never tried NASM( maybe after I will finish my game). It will be great to see your game code!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I finally got **TASM+TLINK** to work with **Windows 7 x64** ... ([VirtualPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) is not working *properly* any more :()

So here is one simple Tunnelers-like game for three players in **TASM** `tiny` model (***.com**).

It is unfinished (I moved to **NASM** at that time), but you can redefine keys, and move the cars with the keyboard (all players). This is how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

On the left is the main menu, on right the game (after hitting the `0` option). It should cover all the basics you need for your task. The source code is divided to three files:

**Battle.asm** - main game source file

```cpp
mx    equ 256
my    equ 256
ox    equ 104
oy    equ 104

    .386P
    IDEAL
    MODEL tiny

    DATASEG
mems:
msg    db '0  Start game.',0
    db '1  Read info.',0
    db '2  Redefine keyboard.',0
    db '3  Exit to DOS.',0
    db 'SPEKTRA software & hardware presents:  Battle zone.',0
    db 'ver: 2.0  x.4.1999  N.DCA SR',0
    db 'Defined keys: ',0
msg1    db 5
    db 'Battle zone.',13,13
    db 'This is only a test version. The full version will be done soon.',13
    db 'It will be slower, but the map will be larger!!! (min 768*256)',13
    db 'Sound Blaster owners will have sound durring game.',13
msg2    db 'Player',0
    db 'Left  ',0
    db 'Right ',0
    db 'Up    ',0
    db 'Down  ',0
    db 'Fire  ',0
msg2a   db 'WARNING: do not use the extended keys of 101-keys keyboard'
    db ' ie: End,arrows,...',0
msg2b    db 'Press any key to continue.',0

keyn    db  0,0                ;keyscan, keycode
    db  1,1
    db  2,'1'
    db  3,'2'
    db  4,'3'
    db  5,'4'
    db  6,'5'
    db  7,'6'
    db  8,'7'
    db  9,'8'
    db 10,'9'
    db 11,'0'
    db 12,'_'
    db 13,'+'
    db 14,27    ;backspace
    db 15,29
    db 16,'Q'
    db 17,'W'
    db 18,'E'
    db 19,'R'
    db 20,'T'
    db 21,'Y'
    db 22,'U'
    db 23,'I'
    db 24,'O'
    db 25,'P'
    db 26,'{'
    db 27,'}'
    db 28,1        ;enter
    db 29,1
    db 30,'A'
    db 31,'S'
    db 32,'D'
    db 33,'F'
    db 34,'G'
    db 35,'H'
    db 36,'J'
    db 37,'K'
    db 38,'L'
    db 39,':'
    db 40,'"'
    db 41,'~'
    db 42,24
    db 43,'\'
    db 44,'Z'
    db 45,'X'
    db 46,'C'
    db 47,'V'
    db 48,'B'
    db 49,'N'
    db 50,'M'
    db 51,'<'
    db 52,'>'
    db 53,'?'
    db 54,24
    db 55,'*'
    db 56,1
    db 57,' '
    db 58,1
    db 59,1
    db 60,1
    db 61,1
    db 62,1
    db 63,1
    db 64,1
    db 65,1
    db 66,1
    db 67,1
    db 68,1
    db 69,1
    db 70,1
    db 71,'7'
    db 72,'8'
    db 73,'9'
    db 74,'-'
    db 75,'4'
    db 76,'5'
    db 77,'6'
    db 78,'+'
    db 79,'1'
    db 80,'2'
    db 81,'3'
    db 82,'0'
    db 83,'.'    ;delete
    db 87,1
    db 88,1
    db,255
keye    db 28,1        ;enter
    db 29,1
    db 42,1
    db 53,'/'
    db 55,1
    db 56,1
    db 71,1
    db 72,30
    db 73,1
    db 75,17
    db 77,16
    db 79,1
    db 80,31
    db 81,1
    db 82,1
    db 83,1        ;delete
    db,255

key    db 0,0,0            ;keyscan (word), key code(call keys)
fil0    db 'battle.gfx',0
fil1    db 'battle.lvl',0
gfx    db 9216 dup (?)
pal    db 768 dup (?)
car1    db 256 dup (?)
car2    db 256 dup (?)
car3    db 256 dup (?)
lvl    db mx*my/256 dup (?)
carx    dw ?,?,?
cary    dw ?,?,?
plk1    db 33 dup (?)            ;redefine (w), status keys (5 bit)
maps    dw ?

    CODESEG
    STARTUPCODE
    jmp main

    include 'file.inc'
    include 'text.inc'

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Interrupts: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
int09:    cli                ;keyboard ... sets keyscan a
    pushf                ;        key result pl.1,2,3
    pusha
    push ds
    mov ds,[cs:dss]
    in al,60h
    sub ah,ah
    mov [word ptr key],ax
    in al,61h
    mov ah,al
    or al,80h
    out 61h,al
    xchg al,ah
    out 61h,al
    mov al,20h
    out 20h,al
    mov al,[key]        ;handle extended keyscan
    cmp al,224
    jnz i09r0
    mov [key+1],al
    in al,60h
    mov [key],al
    in al,61h
    mov ah,al
    or al,80h
    out 61h,al
    xchg al,ah
    out 61h,al
    mov al,20h
    out 20h,al
i09r0:  mov ax,[word ptr key]
    lea si,[plk1]                ;set keyresult if hit
    lea di,[plk1+10]
    mov cx,3
i09p1x:    push cx
    mov dl,1
    mov cx,5
i09p10:    cmp ax,[ds:si]
    jz i09p11
    inc si
    inc si
    add dl,dl
    loop i09p10
    jmp i09p12
i09p11: or [ds:di],dl
i09p12: pop cx
    inc si
    add di,11
    loop i09p1x
    test al,128                ;res keyresult if drop
    jz i09r2
    and al,127
    lea si,[plk1]
    lea di,[plk1+10]
    mov cx,3
i09p2x:    push cx
    mov dl,1
    mov cx,5
i09p20:    cmp ax,[ds:si]
    jz i09p21
    inc si
    inc si
    add dl,dl
    loop i09p20
    jmp i09p22
i09p21: sub [ds:di],dl
i09p22: pop cx
    inc si
    add di,11
    loop i09p2x
i09r2:    mov al,[key]                ;if no key then keyscan = 0
    and al,128
    jz i09r1
    sub al,al
    mov [key],al
i09r1:    pop ds
    popa
    popf
    sti
    iret
    dss    dw 0
    oint09     dw 0,0                ;old vector adress
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Subroutines: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
keys:    pusha                    ;set keycode of ax key
    lea si,[keyn]
    mov bl,2
    sub cl,cl
    or ah,ah
    jz keyl0
    lea si,[keye]
keyl0:    mov ah,[ds:si]
    cmp ah,255
    jz keyre
    cmp al,ah
    jz keyr0
    inc si
    inc si
    jmp keyl0
keyr0:  inc si
    mov bl,[ds:si]
keyre:    mov [key+2],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
ikey:     mov ax,[word ptr key]            ;ax = keyscan pressed key
    or ax,ax
    jnz ikey
ikeyl0: mov ax,[word ptr key]
    or al,al
    jz ikeyl0
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
txtcls:    pusha
    mov di,0
    mov al,32
txtcls0:mov [es:di],al
    inc di
    inc di
    cmp di,80*25*2
    jnz txtcls0
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Main program: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
main:    mov [cs:dss],ds
    mov al,9h        ;install keyboard int
    mov ah,35h
    int 21h
    mov [oint09],bx
    mov [oint09+2],es
    mov al,9h
    mov ah,25h
    lea dx,[int09]
    int 21h

open:    lea dx,[fil0]                ;load gfx
    call fopen
    lea dx,[gfx]
    mov cx,9984
    call fread
    call fclose

    mov ax,cs                ;relocate memory
    mov es,ax
    mov bx,8192
    mov ah,4Ah
    int 21h

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
begin:    mov ax,3                ;main window
    int 16

    lea dx,[fil1]                ;load level
    call fopen
    lea dx,[lvl]
    mov cx,mx*my/256+12+33
    call fread
    call fclose

    mov ah,2
    mov bh,0
    mov dx,25*256
    int 16
    mov ax,0B800h
    mov es,ax
    lea si,[msg]
    mov di,2*(31+08*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(31+10*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(31+12*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(31+14*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(15+1*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(24+2*80)
    call print
    mov di,2*(8+19*80)
    call print
    lea si,[plk1]
    mov cx,3
beginl1:push cx
    add di,4
    mov ax,[ds:si]
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc si
    add di,8
    mov ax,[ds:si]
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc si
    sub di,4+320
    mov ax,[ds:si]
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc si
    add di,640
    mov ax,[ds:si]
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc si
    sub di,320
    mov ax,[ds:si]
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc si
    add di,20
    inc si
    pop cx
    loop beginl1
beginl0:mov ax,[word ptr key]
    cmp ax,1
    jz ende
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    cmp al,'0'
    jz game
    cmp al,'1'
    jz info
    cmp al,'2'
    jz redef
    cmp al,'3'
    jz ende
    jmp beginl0
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
redef:     call txtcls            ;Redefine window
    mov di,2*(0+01*80)
    lea si,[msg2a]
    call print
    push si
    mov cx,3
    lea bx,[plk1]
    mov di,2*(4+04*80)
redefl1:lea si,[msg2]
    push cx
    push di
    call print
    mov al,'4'
    sub al,cl
    mov [es:di],al
    inc di
    inc di
    mov al,':'
    mov [es:di],al
    add di,4
    mov cx,5
redefl0:push di
    call print
    call ikey
    mov [ds:bx],ax
    call keys
    mov al,[key+2]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc bx
    inc bx
    pop di
    add di,160
    loop redefl0
    pop di
    add di,44
    inc bx
    pop cx
    loop redefl1
    pop si
    mov di,2*(25+16*80)
    call print
    call ikey
redefr0:mov ax,[word ptr key]
    or ax,ax
    jnz redefr0
    cli
    sub al,al            ;delete directions
    mov [cs:plk1+10],al
    mov [cs:plk1+21],al
    mov [cs:plk1+32],al
    sti
    lea dx,[fil1]            ;save redef
    call fopen
    lea dx,[lvl]
    mov cx,mx*my/256+12+33
    call fwrite
    call fclose
    jmp begin
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
info:    call txtcls            ;info window
    mov di,2*(0+01*80)
    lea si,[msg1+1]
    mov cl,[msg1]
    sub ch,ch
infol0: push cx
    call print
    pop cx
    loop infol0
    lea si,[msg2b]
    mov di,2*(25+24*80)
    call print
    call ikey
infor0: mov ax,[word ptr key]
    or ax,ax
    jnz infor0
    jmp begin

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Main window: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mapi:    pusha
    push es
    mov es,[maps]
    sub di,di
    lea bx,[lvl]
    lea si,[gfx]
    sub al,al
    mov cx,my/16
mapl3:    push cx
    mov cx,mx/16
mapl2:    push cx
    push si
    mov ah,[ds:bx]
    add si,ax
    mov cx,16
mapl1:    push cx
    mov cx,4
    rep movsd
    add di,mx-16
    pop cx
    loop mapl1
    pop si
    sub di,16*mx-16
    inc bx
    pop cx
    loop mapl2
    add di,15*mx
    pop cx
    loop mapl3
    pop es
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
car:    pusha                    ;ax=direction es:di=map posiotion ch=car
    push es
    lea si,[gfx+7168]
    add si,ax
    lea bx,[car1-256]
    sub cl,cl
    add bx,cx
    mov cx,16
    mov dl,15
carl1:    push cx
    mov cx,16
carl0:  mov al,[ds:si]
    mov ah,[es:di]
    mov [cs:bx],ah
    cmp al,dl
    jz carx0
    mov [es:di],al
carx0:    inc bx
    inc si
    inc di
    loop carl0
    add di,mx-16
    pop cx
    loop carl1
    pop es
    popa
    ret
cart:    db 255,0,4,255,2,1,3,255,6,7,5,255,255,255,255,255
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
carz:    pusha                    ;es:di=map position ch=car
    push es
    lea si,[car1-256]
    sub cl,cl
    add si,cx
    mov cx,16
carzl1:    push cx
    mov cx,16
carzl0:    mov al,[cs:si]
    mov [es:di],al
    inc si
    inc di
    loop carzl0
    add di,mx-16
    pop cx
    loop carzl1
    pop es
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
carn1:    pusha            ;bx = [plk1 +...] cx =[cary] dh=pl
    push es
    push ds
    push di
    mov al,[cs:bx]
    and al,15
    lea bx,[cart]
    xlatb
    xchg al,ah
    sub al,al
    mov bx,cx
    cmp ah,255
    jz carn1e
    mov di,[cs:bx]
    mov es,[maps]
    mov ch,dh
    call carz
    sub bx,6
    mov di,[cs:bx]        ;player

xxx:    pusha
    mov ah,1
    mov ch,16
crnl1:  mov cl,16
crnl0:    mov al,[es:di]
    or al,al
    jnz crnrx
    sub ah,ah
crnrx:    inc di
    dec cl
    jnz crnl0
    add di,256-16
    dec ch
    jnz crnl1
    or ah,ah
    jnz crnry
    mov ax,[cs:bx+6]
    mov [cs:bx],ax
crnry:    popa
    mov di,[cs:bx]

    call car
    mov ax,[cs:bx]
    add bx,6
    mov [cs:bx],ax
    sub bx,6

carn1e:    mov ds,[maps]
    mov ax,[cs:bx]
    sub al,44
    jnc carn1a
    sub al,al
carn1a:    cmp al,152
    jc carn1c
    mov al,152
carn1c:    sub ah,44
    jnc carn1b
    sub ah,ah
carn1b: cmp ah,152
    jc carn1d
    mov ah,152
carn1d:    mov si,ax
    pop di
    call obr
    pop ds
    pop es
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
obr:    push ds                ;0A000h:di,ds:si
    push es
    mov ax,0A000h
    mov es,ax
    mov cx,oy
obrl1:    push cx
    mov cx,ox/4
    rep movsd
    pop cx
    add di,320-ox
    add si,mx-ox
    loop obrl1
    pop es
    pop ds
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
ctrl:    pusha                  ;controls al,keyresult di=[carx]
    lea bx,[cart]
    push ax
    xlat
    pop bx
    xchg ax,bx
    cmp bl,255
    mov bx,[cs:di]
    jz c13
    mov ah,2        ;step
    test al,1
    jz c10
    sub bl,ah
    jnc c10
    add bl,ah
c10:    test al,2
    jz c11
    add bl,ah
    cmp bl,240
    jc c11
    sub bl,ah
c11:    test al,4
    jz c12
    sub bh,ah
    jnc c12
    add bh,ah
c12:    test al,8
    jz c13
    add bh,ah
    cmp bh,240
    jc c13
    sub bh,ah
c13:    mov [cs:di],bx
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

game:    mov ax,19        ;game
    int 16

    lea bx,[pal]
    mov dx,3C8h        ;set palete
    mov cl,0
pall0:    mov al,cl
    out dx,al
    inc dx
    mov al,[cs:bx]
    inc bx
    out dx,al
    mov al,[cs:bx]
    inc bx
    out dx,al
    mov al,[cs:bx]
    inc bx
    out dx,al
    dec dx
    inc cl
    jnz pall0

getm:    mov ah,48h
    mov bx,12288
    int 21h
    mov [maps],ax
    jc gerr
    call mapi
    mov es,[maps]
    mov di,[cary]
    mov ax,2*256
    mov ch,1        ;player
    call car
    mov di,[cary+2]
    mov ch,2        ;player
    call car
    mov di,[cary+4]
    mov ch,3        ;player
    call car

gl0:    lea bx,[plk1+10]
    lea cx,[cary]
    mov di,0
    mov dh,1
    call carn1
    lea bx,[plk1+21]
    lea cx,[cary+2]
    mov di,ox+4
    mov dh,2
    call carn1
    lea bx,[plk1+32]
    lea cx,[cary+4]
    mov di,ox+ox+8
    mov dh,3
    call carn1

    mov al,[plk1+10]
    lea di,[carx]
    call ctrl
    mov al,[plk1+21]
    lea di,[carx+2]
    call ctrl
    mov al,[plk1+32]
    lea di,[carx+4]
    call ctrl

    mov ax,[word ptr key]
    cmp ax,1
    jnz gl0

freem:    mov ah,49h
    mov es,[maps]
    int 21h
gamee0:    mov al,[key]
    or al,al
    jnz gamee0
    jmp begin

gerrm    db 'Memory alocation error.',0
gerr:    mov ax,3
    int 16
    sub di,di
    lea si,[gerrm]
    mov ax,0B800h
    mov es,ax
    call print
    jmp gamee0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
ende:    push ds            ;uninstall keyboard int
    mov dx,[oint09]
    mov ax,[oint09+2]
    mov ds,ax
    mov al,9h
    mov ah,25h
    int 21h
    pop ds
    mov ax,3
    int 16

    EXITCODE
meme:
    END
```

**file.inc** - lib for disc file access

```cpp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;   File library:   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
hand    dw 0        ;###    handler...
ferr    db 0        ;###    DOS error code
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fopen:    pusha        ;DS:DX = file name, [hand] <= file handle
    mov ax,3D02h
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fopen0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fopen0: mov [cs:hand],ax
    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fnew:    pusha        ;DS:DX = file name, [hand] <= file handle
    mov ah,3ch
    mov cx,0    ;attr
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fnew0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fnew0:    mov [cs:hand],ax
    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fclose:    pusha        ;[hand] = file handle
    mov bx,[cs:hand]
    mov ah,3eh
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fclose0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fclose0:mov [cs:ferr],bl
    mov [cs:hand],ax
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fread:    pusha        ;DS:DX = adr, CX = length, [hand] = hand, CX => read
    mov bx,[cs:hand]
    mov ah,3Fh
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fread0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fread0:    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    mov cx,ax
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fwrite:    pusha        ;DS:DX = adr, CX = length, [hand] = hand, CX => write
    mov bx,[cs:hand]
    mov ah,40h
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fwrite0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fwrite0:mov [cs:ferr],bl
    mov cx,ax
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fdel:    pusha        ;DS:DX = file name
    mov ah,41h
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fdel0
    mov bl,al
fdel0:    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fattr:    pusha        ;DS:DX = file name, CX = attr
    mov ax,4301h    ;4300 for attr read => cx ... change push/pop
    int 21h        ;        7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
    mov bl,0    ;cx = attr:     0 0 A 0 0 S H R
    jnc fattr0
    mov bl,al
fattr0:    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

**text.inc** - lib for text printing in text mode 3

```cpp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;   TXT mode 3 library:   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
kurxy:    pusha        ;dl = column, dh = row    set kursor position
    mov ah,2
    sub bh,bh
    int 16
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
print:  push ax        ;DS:SI data => ES:DI screen
    push es
    push 0B800h
    pop es
    mov ah,13
    push di
prnl0:    mov al,[ds:si]
    cmp al,ah
    jz prnr0
    or al,al
    jz prnr1
    mov [es:di],al
prnr0:    inc di
    inc di
    inc si
    cmp al,ah
    jnz prnl0
    pop di
    add di,160            ;next line
    pop es
    pop ax
    ret
prnr1:    pop ax                ;end without ENTER
    inc di
    inc di
    inc si
    pop es
    pop ax
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

**battle.lvl** - level map layout

I do not know how to post this file here  so here **hex** output instead

[image: battle.lvl]

It is 16x16 sprites map the rest is additional information. Where `(mx,my)` is size of map in pixels and sprite size is `16x16` ...

**battle.gfx** - raw unpacked sprites

I do not know how to post also this file so here just two images of what is inside

[image: battle.gfx]

[image: battle.gfx]

Each sprite is `16x16` pixels/bytes. File contains `36` sprites + `768` Byte palette = `9984` bytes. White color is invisible (transparent). I think the sprites are in that order and palette is on end of file (not sure thou...) also sprite index is from `0`. I think it matches the battle.lvl codes ...

Here the demo for download:

- [TASM MS-DOS game demo](http://ulozto.net/xU8KA5Ft/battle-rar)

the `*.com,*.gfx,*.lvl` are needed to run this the rest is source code.

**[notes]**

Sorry, if forget to translate some comments, but the code is pretty straightforward I hope.

**[PS]**

After moving to **NASM** I added some new features like AI, Guns,... it looks like this (but also never finished it ... but it was playable already)

[image: Battle NASM]

Just tried it on **DOSBox**, but it was painfully slow in comparison to my **AMD K5 120 MHz** days (until I realized I need to add more cycles for **DOSBox** :)...)

Comment: This is amaing. Thank you so much for your help. I hope This will solve alot of problems :). Really appreaciate it!

Comment: @Orange finally finished editing ... take me a lot of time to actualy make this compilable because my TASM/TLINK was not working as should and also have lost one inc file so I was searching for something compatible ... compilation is done `tasm battle.asm` and `tlink /t battle.obj` cant share the level and gfx file directly here so the level you can type your self from hexdump and gfx is more tricky so I probably upload the whole thing somewhere in a while

Comment: Ok, Thank you once again

Comment: @Orange here it is http://ulozto.sk/xU8KA5Ft/battle-rar just click on the stiahnut yellow button fill in the 4 characters from image and click stiahnut button again that should start download ... The `*.com,*.gfx,*.lvl` files are needed to run it rest is source or images for this answer

Comment: It looks awesome. My game will not reach this level of programing, but your code is very helpfull.