# How to color the screen in graphic mode in DOS operation system?

Tags: assembly, graphics, int, dos

in a University project in graphic mode in DOS operrarion system I need to clear the screen (color it all in one color), does anyone know what's the intterapt for that and what do I need to put in the registers? In which register put the color i want the screen will be in? thank very much to the helpers!

this is my code (in assembly): if someone can help me understand why the up & down arrowes are moving right & left  and why my exit is writing me deternmind code 0 I would love that!:

> ```
> > IDEAL MODEL 
> small STACK 
> 100h DATASEG 
> x dw 0 
> xa dw 0 
> y dw 5 
> ya dw 5 
> z dw 1
> za dw 1 
> color db 4
> Pixels Color bgcolor db 0 ;BackGround Color
> > CODESEG start: 
> mov ax, @data 
> mov ds, ax 
> ; Graphic mode 
> mov ax, 13h 
> int 10h
> ; Print red dot 
> mov bh,0h 
> mov cx,[x] 
> mov dx,[y]
> > mov al,[color] 
> mov ah,0ch 
> int 10h 
> amit:
> >     ;Wait for +
> >     mov ah,00h
> >     int 16h
> >     cmp ax, 0d3dh
> >     je plus
> >     ;Wait for -
> >     cmp ax, 0c2dh
> >     je minus
> >     ; Wait for exit
> >     cmp ax, 1071h
> >     je exit
> >     cmp ax, 4d00h
> >     je right
> >     cmp ax, 4b00h
> >     je left1
> >     cmp ax, 4800h
> >     je up1
> >     cmp ax, 5000h
> >     je down1
> >     
> >     exit:
> >         mov ah, 0
> >         mov al, 2
> >         int 10h
> >         mov ax, 4c00h
> >         int 21h
> >     plus:
> >         add [x], 1
> >         mov cx, [x]
> >         add [y], 1
> >         mov dx, [y]
> >         mov bh, 0h
> >         mov al,[color]
> >         mov ah, 0ch
> >         int 10h
> >         add [z], 1h
> >         add [za], 1h
> >         jmp amit
> >     left1:
> >         jmp left
> >     up1:
> >         jmp up
> >     down1:
> >         jmp down
> >     minus:
> >         mov bh, 00h
> >         mov al,[bgcolor]
> >         mov ah,0ch
> >         int 10h
> >         sub [x], 1
> >         mov cx, [x]
> >         sub [y], 1
> >         mov dx, [y]
> >         sub [z], 1h
> >         sub [za], 1h
> >         jmp amit
> >     right:
> >         clsright:
> >             mov bh, 00h
> >             mov al,[bgcolor]
> >             mov ah,0ch
> >             int 10h
> >             sub [x], 1
> >             mov cx, [x]
> >             sub [y], 1
> >             mov dx, [y]
> >             sub [z], 1h
> >             cmp [z], 0h
> >             jne clsright  
> >         add [x],1h
> >         jmp arrowplus
> >     left:
> >         clsleft:
> >             mov bh, 00h
> >             mov al,[bgcolor]
> >             mov ah,0ch
> >             int 10h
> >             sub [x], 1
> >             mov cx, [x]
> >             sub [y], 1
> >             mov dx, [y]
> >             sub [z], 1h
> >             cmp [z], 0h
> >             jne clsleft 
> >             sub [x], 1h
> >             jmp arrowplus
> >     up:
> >         clsup:
> >             mov bh, 00h
> >             mov al,[bgcolor]
> >             mov ah,0ch
> >             int 10h
> >             sub [x], 1
> >             mov cx, [x]
> >             sub [y], 1
> >             mov dx, [y]
> >             sub [z], 1h
> >             cmp [z], 0h
> >             jne clsup 
> >             sub [y], 1h
> >             jmp arrowplus
> >     down:
> >         clsdown:
> >             mov bh, 00h
> >             mov al,[bgcolor]
> >             mov ah,0ch
> >             int 10h
> >             sub [x], 1
> >             mov cx, [x]
> >             sub [y], 1
> >             mov dx, [y]
> >             sub [z], 1h
> >             cmp [z], 0h
> >             jne clsdown
> >             add [y], 1h
> >             jmp arrowplus
> >     arrowplus:
> >         add [x], 1
> >         mov cx, [x]
> >         add [y], 1
> >         mov dx, [y]
> >         mov bh, 0h
> >         mov al,[color]
> >         mov ah, 0ch
> >         int 10h
> >         add [z], 1h
> >         mov [z], dx
> >         cmp [za], dx
> >         jne arrowplus
> >         jmp amit END start
> ```

Comment: I would update video memory directly to manipulate bits on the screen, but you can use the very slow method using the BIOS [Int 10h/AH=0Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0104.htm)

Comment: if you need later on some more things to add to your project see [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214) I put there source for one of my really old game in MS-DOS 320x200x8bit mode (the same you are using) including menu (in text mode), sprites, simultaneous control (3 players) , file access. All in tiny model (up to 64KB of *.com executable)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are working with VGA mode (or can switch to VGA).
There's a good explanation about the different modes [here](http://www.wagemakers.be/english/doc/vga).
Briefly, you can switch to several display modes, either graphical or textual.
For all legacy modes, including VGA, you can interact with the dispaly through an interrupt, but it's quite clumsy. A better option, is using DMA (Direct Memory Access). It's an interval of memory addresses, which is mapped directly to the display memory. So by writing a byte to the memory, you can change a character/pixel/pixels (depending on the exact mode).
The easiest for you will be to switch to VGA 16 color, and writing a constant byte the the display.
You can find information about the interacting with the monitor using DMA [here](http://devdocs.inightmare.org/x86-assembly-graphics-part-i-mode-13h/), and a color palette for this mode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#Color_palette).

A sample code (credit to [this](http://devdocs.inightmare.org/x86-assembly-graphics-part-i-mode-13h/) page):

```
mov ax, 13h ; AH=0 (Change video mode), AL=13h (VGA mode, 16 colors, 320x200)
int 10h ; Video BIOS interrupt, switching to VGA
mov ax, 0A000h ; The offset to video mapped memory
mov es, ax ; We load it to ES through AX, becouse immediate operation is not allowed on ES
mov ax, 0 ; 0 will put it in top left corner. To put it in top right corner load with 320, in the middle of the screen 32160 = 320*100 + 160.
mov di, ax ; load Destination Index register with ax value (the coords to put the pixel)
mov al, 7 ; Grey color.
mov cx, 64000 ; 6400 = 320 * 200 pixels
rep stosb ; paint the whole screen with grey
```

The color palette for this mode, for the sake of completeness:

```
0 - black
1 - blue
2 - green
3 - cyan
4 - red
5 - magenta
6 - brown
7 - light gray
8 - gray
9 - light blue
10 - light green
11 - light cyan
12 - light red
13 - light magenta
14 - yellow
15 - white
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code for each way you suggest?

Comment: There are sample codes in the links. I'll attach one anyhow.

Comment: Sometimes links become unavailable. Posting the codes here preserve your ideas.