# Borland c++ console functions

Tags: c++, dos, turbo-c++, borland-c++, borland-c

I'm studing now and I got this homework / tasks to do:

1) If you press the `CTRL + L` key, all numeric symbols should change the color.

2) If you press the `CTRL + S` key, you will get the length of the word, left from the cursor.

I found this function `int bioskey(int cmd);`
So now I can check if the key is pressed, but how to change the color only of numeric symbols, or read words from console to get their length ?

Comment: Good question. Been about 20 years since I used Turbo C++.

Comment: Get a modern compiler.

Comment: You do it in a similar way as you would for Object Pascal, Perl, or B. Seriously, *get a more up to date compiler*.

Comment: The POINT is to make this project for DOS

Comment: I don't use an old compiler in real application, but our teachers are some times strange peoplse

Comment: And now you learn things that we have already forgotten, because nobody does that anymore. Too bad.

Comment: Well, not my fault :(

Comment: But looks like i should delete this question

Comment: Added answer. From my point of view it is a valid question (even if title may be a bit misleading). If you are bound to some IDE/compiler/platform then comments to use something else are not really helpful and sound more like excuses how something not to get done instead of helping. I know TC++ is "really" outdated but that is irrelevant in this case. Anyway newest does not mean better and usually only leads to more unnecessarily work later (appart from some exceptions) and lead us to the state of the Art mess we are now in SW world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of us still remember the **MS-DOS** (let it rest in peace or pieces...)

if you are really in **MS-DOS** then you can not expect that the content of the console would be changed in colors for only specific areas. You need to do that your self. The problem is we do not know anything about your project background so we do not know what and how yours stuff is represented,rendered/outputed/inputed etc...

I assume **EGA/VGA BIOS** text mode is used so you can exploit direct access to the **VRAM**. So you need to set pointer to the address `B800:0000` and handle it as array where each character on screen has 2 BYTEs. one is color attribute and the other is **ASCII** code (not sure in which order anymore)...

So for already rendered stuff you just:

1. **loop through whole screen**

   usually `80x25x2` Bytes
2. **test each ASCII for alpha numeric value**

   so ASCII `code >= '0'` and `code<='9'` for numbers or add all the stuff you are considering as alphanumeric like `code>' '` and `code<='9'`.
3. **change colors for selected characters**

   just by changing the attribute byte.

When you put it together for numbers it will look like this:

```
char far *scr=(char far*)0x0B0000000;
int x,y,a;
for (a=0,y=0;y<25;y++)
 for (x=0;x<80;x++,a+=2)
  if ((scr[a+0]>='0')&&((scr[a+0]<='9'))
  {
  scr[a+1]=7; //attribute with the different color here
  }
```

if it does not work than try swap `scr[a+0]` and `scr[a+1]`. If an exception occur then you are not in **MS-DOS** and you do not have access to **VRAM**. In that case  use **DOS-BOX** or driver that allows access to memory like dllportio ...
For more info see some more or less related QA's:

- [Display an array of color in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)
- [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214)

If you got problem with the `CTRL+Key` detection not sure if in-build function in **TC++** allows `CTRL` (was too long ago) then you can exploit **BIOS** or even hook up the keyboard **ISR**. See the second link where **ISR** for keyboard handler is there present... You can port it to **C++** or google there must be a lot of examples out there especially **TP7.0** (which is pascal but easily portable to **TC++**)