# Set and reset keyboard Interrupt Service Routines in x86 real mode within DOS with Assembly

Tags: assembly, keyboard, interrupt-handling, tasm, x86-16

How do you properly set, and then reset, the keyboard ISR in DOS? (x86 assembly, real mode, 16 bit, with TASM)

I have the following assembly code which sets up my ISR for the keyboard.  All it is supposed to do is print out a sentence each time a key is pressed, up to five times.  Then it is supposed to exit.

It seems like the ISR is being installed correctly.  It will print out a sentence each time a key is pressed (once for down, once for up).  However, it appears as though I am uninstalling the ISR incorrectly as I'm unable to enter text into the DOS command line after running the program.

(I have updated the code below to store/restore DS in the ISR, read from port 60h, and handle EOI calls thanks to feedback received so far.)

```
.model              small
.data

our_text            db      "Interrupt intercepted", 0dh, 0ah, "$"
old_int_seg         dw      0
old_int_off         dw      0
keyCount            dw      0
.code
.startup
                    cli
                    mov     ah, 035             ; get current keyboard int vector
                    mov     al, 09h             ; and save it, so we can restore it later
                    int     21h                 
                    mov     [old_int_off], bx   
                    mov     bx, es
                    mov     [old_int_seg], bx

                    mov     ax, cs
                    mov     ds, ax              ; load data segment with code segment 
                                                ;(the one we are in now)
                    mov     ah, 25h             ; Set Interrupt Vector Command
                    mov     al, 9               ; Interrupt to replace
                    lea     dx, ISR             ;load dx with our interrupt address
                    int     21h
                    sti

                    mov     ax,@data
                    mov     ds,ax
infinite:
                    mov     ax,keyCount[0]
                    cmp     ax,5
                    jl      infinite                ;check for 5 presses


                    cli                             ;restore old interrupt
                    mov     ax, [old_int_seg]
                    mov     ds, ax
                    mov     dx, [old_int_off]
                    mov     ah, 25h
                    mov     al, 09h
                    int     21h
                    sti

                    mov     ah,4Ch                  ; quit
                    mov     al,00h
                    int     21h

ISR                 proc    far
                                                    ; save old registers
                    push    ax
                    push    cx
                    push    dx
                    push    bx
                    push    sp
                    push    bp
                    push    si
                    push    di
                    push    ds

                    mov     ax,@data                ;print text
                    mov     ds,ax
                    xor     ah,ah
                    mov     ah, 9
                    lea     dx, our_text
                    int     21h

                    mov     ax,keyCount
                    inc     ax
                    mov     [keyCount],ax

                    in      al, 60h

                    ; send EOI to keyboard
                    in      al, 61h
                    mov     ah, al
                    or      al, 80h
                    out     61h, al
                    mov     al, ah
                    out     61h, al

                    ; send EOI to master PIC
                    mov     al, 20h
                    out     20h, al

                    pop     ds
                    pop     di
                    pop     si
                    pop     bp
                    pop     sp
                    pop     bx
                    pop     dx
                    pop     cx
                    pop     ax
                    iret
ISR                 endp
```

What's wrong with how I'm restoring the original keyboard ISR?  Why am I unable to type anything into the command prompt in DOS after running the program?

Comment: Your ISR for the keyboard must read a byte from port 0x60 otherwise you won't get subsequent interrupts occurring. You also have to send an End of Interrupt to the PIC (programmable interrupt controller)

Comment: Since you change _DS_ your interrupt handler should also save and restore the value of _DS_ just like all the other registers you potentially modify.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thanks for the excellent suggestions.  I am now reading the byte from 0x60, sending out an EOI signal to the keyboard and PIC, and save/restoring DS.  (I have updated all the code in my question to reflect these changes.)  The program runs correctly now except for one small thing: I am unable to enter any text into the DOS command line after the program terminates, so I think I'm not restoring the original ISR correctly?

Comment: `mov     ah, 035` should be `mov     ah, 35h` . You called the wrong software interrupt and acquired garbage for a vector. Another issue is that this code is incorrect: `mov     ax, [old_int_seg]`
                    `mov     ds, ax`
                    `mov     dx, [old_int_off]` You change _DS_ before you read the offset which is incorrect. Should be `mov     ax, [old_int_seg]`
                    `mov     dx, [old_int_off]`
                    `mov     ds, ax`

Comment: You are brilliant!  Thank you so very much.  Is there a way for me to give you credit for the answer since you gave it in comments instead?

Comment: That's okay. If you wish you can answer your own question with the information I provided though.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps here is my ancient keyboard handler for **MS-DOS** coded in **NASM**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Keyboard int 09 driver ver: 1.4
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;keywait    wait for change from keyboard scancode >> ax
;keyadr     si<=adr of NAME of keycode in ax
;int09i     install int 09
;int09u     uninstall int 09
;int09      update tab press/pop status (0=pop,255=pressed) and key...
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;key.ascii  ASCII key code      byte
;key.scan   tab key code        word
;key.name   adr of key name in tab  word
;key.tab0/1/2   scan(Byte) ,pressed/poped,ASCII,ASCIIZ
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Subroutines: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
keywait:mov ax,[cs:key.scan];wait for change from keyboard scancode >> ax
.l0:    cmp ax,[cs:key.scan]
    jz  .l0
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
keyadr: push    ax      ;si<=adr of NAME of keycode ax
    cmp ax,197+512      ;not if Pause or Break
    jz  .q0
    cmp ax,198+512
    jz  .q0
    and al,127
.q0:    lea si,[cs:key.tab0]
    cmp ah,0
    jz  .r0
    lea si,[cs:key.tab1]
    cmp ah,1
    jz  .r0
    lea si,[cs:key.tab2]
    cmp ah,2
    jz  .r0
    jmp .err
.r0:    xchg    al,ah
.l0:    mov al,[cs:si]
    add si,3
    cmp al,ah
    jz  .esc
    cmp al,255
    jz  .err
.l1:    mov al,[cs:si]
    inc si
    or  al,al
    jnz .l1
    jmp .l0
.err:   lea si,[cs:.errkey]
.esc:   pop ax
    ret
    db      1,0,'?'
.errkey:db  'Unknown key',0
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
int09i: pusha           ;install int 09
    push    es
    mov     al,9h
    mov     ah,35h
    int     21h
    mov     [cs:int09.vect],bx
    mov     [cs:int09.vect+2],es
    mov     al,9h
    mov     ah,25h
    lea     dx,[cs:int09]
    int     21h
    pop es
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
int09u: push    ds      ;uninstall int 09
    pusha
    mov     dx,[cs:int09.vect]
    mov     ax,[cs:int09.vect+2]
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     al,9h
    mov     ah,25h
    int     21h
    popa
    pop     ds
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Prerusenia: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
int09:  cli         ;keyboard
    pusha
    in  al,60h
    mov bx,[cs:key.stat]
    cmp bl,1
    jz  .r1
    cmp bl,2
    jz  .r2
.r0:    inc bl      ;level0 ... first byte of scan code
    cmp al,0E0h
    jz  .esc
    inc bl
    mov bh,5
    cmp al,0E1h
    jz  .esc
    sub ah,ah       ;normal code
    mov [cs:key.scan],ax
    sub bx,bx
    jmp .esc
.r1:    mov bx,2+256*2  ;level1 ... second byte of scan code
    cmp al,2Ah
    jz  .esc
    cmp al,46h
    jz  .esc
    cmp al,0AAh
    jz  .esc
    mov ah,1        ;extended1 code
    mov [cs:key.scan],ax
    sub bx,bx
    jmp .esc
.r2:    dec bh
    jnz .esc
    mov ah,2        ;extended2 code
    mov [cs:key.scan],ax
    sub bx,bx
.esc:   mov [cs:key.stat],bx
    mov ax,[cs:key.scan]
    call    keyadr
    mov ah,[cs:si-1]    ;ASCII
    mov [cs:key],ah
    mov [cs:key.name],si;NAME ADR
    and al,128
    jz  .keyp1
.keyp0: sub ax,ax
    mov [cs:si-2],al
    mov [cs:key],al
    mov [cs:key.scan],ax
    mov [cs:key.name],word key.tab0+3
    jmp .esc0
.keyp1: mov [cs:si-2],byte 255
.esc0:  in  al,61h      ;end of interrupt ...this is a must
    mov     ah,al
    or  al,80h
    out     61h,al
    xchg    al,ah
    out     61h,al
    mov     al,20h
    out     20h,al
    popa
    sti
    iret
.vect:  dw  0,0

key:
.ascii  db  0       ;ASCII
.scan   dw  0       ;low=key code ,hi=tab 0,1,2
.name   dw  0       ;adr of key NAME

.stat:  db  0,0     ;byte count of code,number of readed byte

;tables:    scancode low(hi is tab 0,1,2),pressed/poped,ASCII,name,0
.tab0:  db      0,0,' ','                 ',0   ;basic scan codes
    db      1,0,'?','Esc',0
    db  2,0,'1','1',0
    db      3,0,'2','2',0
    db      4,0,'3','3',0
    db      5,0,'4','4',0
    db      6,0,'5','5',0
    db      7,0,'6','6',0
    db      8,0,'7','7',0
    db      9,0,'8','8',0
    db  10,0,'9','9',0
    db      11,0,'0','0',0
    db      12,0,'-','-',0
    db      13,0,'=','=',0
    db      14,0, 8 ,'Backspace',0
    db      15,0, 9 ,'Tab',0
    db      16,0,'Q','Q',0
    db      17,0,'W','W',0
    db      18,0,'E','E',0
    db      19,0,'R','R',0
    db      20,0,'T','T',0
    db      21,0,'Y','Y',0
    db      22,0,'U','U',0
    db      23,0,'I','I',0
    db      24,0,'O','O',0
    db      25,0,'P','P',0
    db      26,0,'[','[',0
    db      27,0,']',']',0
    db      28,0, 13,'Enter',0
    db      29,0,'?','L-Ctrl',0
    db      30,0,'A','A',0
    db      31,0,'S','S',0
    db      32,0,'D','D',0
    db      33,0,'F','F',0
    db      34,0,'G','G',0
    db      35,0,'H','H',0
    db      36,0,'J','J',0
    db      37,0,'K','K',0
    db      38,0,'L','L',0
    db      39,0,';',';',0
    db      40,0,'"','"',0
    db      41,0,'~','~',0
    db      42,0,'?','L-Shift',0
    db      43,0,'\','\',0
    db      44,0,'Z','Z',0
    db      45,0,'X','X',0
    db      46,0,'C','C',0
    db      47,0,'V','V',0
    db      48,0,'B','B',0
    db      49,0,'N','N',0
    db      50,0,'M','M',0
    db      51,0,',',',',0
    db      52,0,'.','.',0
    db      53,0,'/','/',0
    db      54,0,'?','R-Shift',0
    db      55,0,'*','Num *',0
    db      56,0,'?','L-Alt',0
    db      57,0,' ','Space',0
    db      58,0,'?','Caps Lock',0
    db      59,0,'?','F1',0
    db      60,0,'?','F2',0
    db      61,0,'?','F3',0
    db      62,0,'?','F4',0
    db      63,0,'?','F5',0
    db      64,0,'?','F6',0
    db      65,0,'?','F7',0
    db      66,0,'?','F8',0
    db      67,0,'?','F9',0
    db      68,0,'?','F10',0
    db      69,0,'?','Num Lock',0
    db      70,0,'?','Scroll Lock',0
    db      71,0,'7','Num 7',0
    db      72,0,'8','Num 8',0
    db      73,0,'9','Num 9',0
    db      74,0,'-','Num -',0
    db      75,0,'4','Num 4',0
    db      76,0,'5','Num 5',0
    db      77,0,'6','Num 6',0
    db      78,0,'+','Num +',0
    db      79,0,'1','Num 1',0
    db      80,0,'2','Num 2',0
    db      81,0,'3','Num 3',0
    db      82,0,'0','Num 0',0
    db      83,0,'.','Num .',0
    db      84,0,'?','Alt-Prnscr',0
    db      87,0,'?','F11',0
    db      88,0,'?','F12',0
    db      255
.tab1:  db      28,0,'?','Num Enter',0  ;scan codes after E0h
    db      29,0,'?','R-Ctrl',0
    db      53,0,'/','Num /',0
    db      55,0,'?','System Request',0
    db      56,0,'?','R-Alt',0
    db      71,0,'?','Home',0
    db      72,0,'?','Up',0
    db      73,0,'?','Page Up',0
    db      75,0,'?','Left',0
    db      77,0,'?','Right',0
    db      79,0,'?','End',0
    db      80,0,'?','Down',0
    db      81,0,'?','Page Down',0
    db      82,0,'?','Ins',0
    db      83,0,'?','Del',0
    db  93,0,'?','Win F2',0
    db      255
.tab2:  db  55,0,'?','Print Screen',0   ;scan codes after E0h AAh E0h
    db      53,0,'?','Shift-Num /',0
    db      71,0,'?','Shift-Home',0
    db      72,0,'?','Shift-Up',0
    db      73,0,'?','Shift-Page Up',0
    db      75,0,'?','Shift-Left',0
    db      77,0,'?','Shift-Right',0
    db      79,0,'?','Shift-End',0
    db      80,0,'?','Shift-Down',0
    db      81,0,'?','Shift-Page Down',0
    db  82,0,'?','Shift-Insert',0
    db  83,0,'?','Shift-Delete',0
    db  197,0,'?','Pause',0
    db  198,0,'?','Break',0
    db  255
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Scan codes constants: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
.esc    equ 1
.n1 equ 2
.n2 equ 3
.n3 equ 4
.n4 equ 5
.n5 equ 6
.n6 equ 7
.n7 equ 8
.n8 equ 9
.n9 equ 10
.n0 equ 11
.minus  equ 12
.equal  equ     13
.bckspc equ     14
.tab    equ     15
.q  equ     16
.w  equ     17
.e  equ     18
.r  equ     19
.t  equ     20
.y  equ     21
.u  equ     22
.i  equ     23
.o  equ     24
.p  equ     25
.enter  equ     28
.lctrl  equ     29
.a  equ     30
.s  equ     31
.d  equ     32
.f  equ     33
.g  equ     34
.h  equ     35
.j  equ     36
.k  equ     37
.l  equ     38
.lshift equ     42
.z  equ     44
.x  equ     45
.c  equ     46
.v  equ     47
.b  equ     48
.n  equ     49
.m  equ     50
.rshift equ     54
.lalt   equ     56
.space  equ     57
.caps   equ     58
.f1 equ     59
.f2 equ     60
.f3 equ     61
.f4 equ     62
.f5 equ     63
.f6 equ     64
.f7 equ     65
.f8 equ     66
.f9 equ     67
.f10    equ     68
.f11    equ     87
.f12    equ     88

.rctrl  equ 256+29
.ralt   equ 256+56
.home   equ 256+71
.up equ 256+72
.pgup   equ 256+73
.left   equ 256+75
.right  equ 256+77
.end    equ 256+79
.down   equ 256+80
.pgdown equ 256+81
.insert equ 256+82
.delete equ 256+83
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; End. ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have since solved the problem with Michael Petch's help and have created a functional ISR for it (but have forgotten to post the answer back here which i will have to do!) which lets me poll for keys rather than wait.   Your code would definitely come in handy when one needs to process one key at a time, correct?  I'm still mew to asm, but that's what it looks like to me.   It also looks well structured and easy to consume, much unlike my first keyboard handlers.  I wish I had it back when I started.

Comment: @MarkInTheDark this code handles any number of keys at once (limited by the keyboard HW of coarse). Each key has its own true/false state which can be probed at any time. I used it for games. If my memory serves well TASM does not know local labels like `.tab0` so you would need to port to TASM style. Not sure if there is some directive for local labels there (my bet is `@`) so if not then all the labels must be renamed to unique global ones ... but may be newer TASM compiler versions  could handle it I use it ages ago...

Comment: @MarkInTheDark if youre interested see also  [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214) it is small ancient asm game in TASM of mine